# Converting docx to images using Aspose.Words

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aspose.words

I'm converting a generated doc to a pdf and to png's, see the code below. But for some reason there is something wrong with the fonts. On my local develop machine everything is right, but when deployed on the production servers the fonts in the PNG's are missing. I've checked but they are installed on the servers. Can someone help me with this?

```
var dstDoc = doc.Clone();
var newInvoice = new InvoicePdf(factuur);
var ds = newInvoice.ToDataSet();
dstDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties.Title = newInvoice.InvoiceID;
dstDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties.Subject = newInvoice.SendDate;
dstDoc.MailMerge.FieldMergingCallback = new HandleMergeFieldAlternatingRows();
dstDoc.MailMerge.ExecuteWithRegions(ds);

var filePath = Path.Combine(folderInvoices, newInvoice.SendDateOrginal.Year.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
var fileName = string.Format("{0} - {1}", newInvoice.InvoiceID, newInvoice.DebtorCompany.ToString(true));
filePath = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);
filePaths.Add(filePath + ".pdf");
dstDoc.Save(filePath + ".pdf", SaveFormat.Pdf);

var options = new ImageSaveOptions(SaveFormat.Png) { PageCount = 1, Resolution = 120, UseAntiAliasing = true, PrettyFormat = true, UseHighQualityRendering = true };
for (var i = 0; i < dstDoc.PageCount; i++)
{
    options.PageIndex = i;
    dstDoc.Save(string.Format("{0}_{1}.png", filePath, i), options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a shared server, then most probably it is a security issue. Aspose.Words for .NET DLL needs access to the Windows registry, to find the fonts folder. Refer to http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/Considerations+When+Running+on+a+Shared+Server+Environment for more details.

A workaround is also possible to specify the path of folder, which has all the required fonts. Please see http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/How+to++Specify+True+Type+Fonts+Location for sample code.

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Comment: We have our own servers, so we don't share them. I'll try to set the path to the folder. But do you think this is different since the PDF are generated correctly.